# Mongodb response

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections:

1. User
2. Profile (contains a user referenced field).

Step 1. fetch **user object** from **user collection** and then use that **user object** to find profile i.e. `->field('user')->reference($user)` is perfectly fine. I'm able to extract other field values of profile collection. E.g `$profile->getX() gives 1 and $profile->getY() gives 2`.

Step 2. If I am using **user object** i.e fetched from another collection suppose **x collection** and use that **user object** directly on profile collection to get values `(->field('user')->reference($user) here $user obtained from x collection)`, I'm unable to get values as expected(same as values obtained from step 1). All field values become **null except primary key id**. `E.g $profile->getX() gives null and $profile->getY() gives null`.

Comment: Format your question properly and provide more details.

Comment: @SagarChaudhary can you help me now?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of caching. Before going through step 2 I did a DB call to the same **profile collection** with limited number select field. so after that,  all DB call results are served from cache.